# How to get data from logged users in views.py? (Django social-auth-app-django)

Tags: django, django-views, social-auth-app-django

I've successfully logged in my facebook account using Social-Auth-App-Django. Now I need to get my user ID so that I can filter the database using the user's ID but I don't have any idea how to do it. In django template it looks like this `{{ user.id }}` but I don't know how to get it in `views.py`

Here's my template code for login into facebook

```
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}" class='btn'>
         <img src="/static/img/facebook.png" alt="">
         Login with Facebook
    </a>
```

And here's my code in `views.py`

```
    @login_required
    def home(request):
         items = Products.objects.filter(product_owner__id=user_id)
         return render(request, 'seller.html', {
             "items": items
    })
```

`user_id` is what I actually need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add your model `Products` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The way you do that would be;

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    items = Products.objects.filter(product_owner=request.user)
    return render(
        request,
        'seller.html',
        {
            "items": items
        }
    )
```

If you didn't have the `login_required` decorator this wouldn't work however. In that case you'd have to check that they're authenticated.

That scenario would look more like;

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        items = Products.objects.filter(product_owner=request.user)
    else:
        items = Products.objects.none()

    return render(
        request,
        'seller.html',
        {
            "items": items
        }
    )
```

Docs relating to this can be found here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests